# Enabled Azure DB Encryption shows 0% complete and in progress after a week

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, tde

With a relatively small database I enabled Transparent Data Encryption.  From SQL server I queried the status of the encryption using this SQL command

```
select * from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
```

The database, after several hours, showed 0 percent complete and encryption state of 2 (not 3).  No problem, I went away for nearly a week and returned to check the status again.  It hasn't changed!  Both the azure portal and SQL report 'in progress'.  I ran DBCC CheckDB() which found no issues.

Has anyone run into this situation?  Is there something else that needs to be done to get this going and completed?

Comment: I'd suggest you submit a support request via portal regarding such issue.